# How can I get access to each individual item by DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom

How would I be able to use javascript to access and click each individual button.  There's a CSS image slider which has these buttons, but I would like to be able to click through each of these tags.

See: https://codepen.io/Groundedelectron/pen/ZaMrKa

```
<div id="slider">
  <a href="#image1">1</a>
  <a href="#image2">2</a>
  <a href="#image3">3</a>
  <a href="#image4">4</a>
</div>
```

Ideally, I would like to be able to get something like `document.getElementById("slider")[1].href.click()`

Something that that I would like to do would be able to use up arrow to scroll through, here's an example of it but with different code:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
     if (e.keyCode == 40) { // space key maps to keycode `27`
       $('#mfcsimminus').click();

    }
});

var minusimagebutton = document.getElementById("mfcsimminus");
minusimagebutton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
cycleimagesmfcSimfunc();
        } , false)

var cyclecount = 0
  function cycleimagesmfcSimfunc(){
        if(cyclecount == 0){
        document.getElementById("mfcSim-CSS").src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16320/dresstop.jpg";
        cyclecount++;
        return;
        }
        if(cyclecount == 1){
        document.getElementById("mfcSim-CSS").src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16320/dresstop.jpg";
        console.log("1");
        cyclecount++;
        return;
        }
}
```

In this case, I would replace     `document.getElementById("mfcSim-CSS").src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16320/dresstop.jpg";` with `document.getElementById("slider")[1].href.click()` and so on.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi guys, nevermind, I'm going to remove the all the images except for one and change it with .src instead  that'll be the better way.  Thanks for checking!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at document.getElementsByTagName (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp).

HTML:

```
<div id="slider">
  <a href="https://www.bbc.com">Coffee</a>
  <a href="https://www.google.com">Tea</a>
  <a href="https://www.cnn.com">Milk</a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
var links = slider.getElementsByTagName("a");
links[1].click();
```